# Block return error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, objective-c-blocks

I am creating a validate method for my application, hover I am having problems with the return value;

**Incompatible block pointer type sending char ...**

```
-(BOOL)validateEmail{

    if (self.ownUser.emailUser != self.emailField) {
        [UserAPIClient validateEmail:self.emailField sucess:^(BOOL sucess, NSError *error) {
            if (sucess) {
                return YES;
            }else{
                NSLog(@"Can´t change e mail, already one is created in the database");
                return NO;
            }
        }];

    }else{
         return YES;
    }
}
```

Can anybody help me solve this?

Thanks in advance...

**EDIT**

I completily missed the right solution, just adopt my **UserApiClient** to return a BOOL

```
-(BOOL)validateEmail{

if (self.ownUser.emailUser != self.emailField) {

    return [UserAPIClient validateEmail:self.emailField];
}else{
    return YES;
}
```

}

**EDIT 2**
Know, i just realized, that i need the result of this method to make some changes after.
How can i change this method to an sync´s Method?

```
    [[MYApiClient sharedInstance] getPath:@"validateEmail" parameters:params
                                    success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id JSON) {

                                        NSLog(@"SUCESS %@", JSON);
                                    }
                                    failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

                                        NSLog(@"Error  %@", error);

                                    }];
```

Comment: You need to post the declaration `[User validateEmail:sucess:]` and tell us its semantics in order to properly answer this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the value of `sucess` outside of the block, you have to copy it to a `__block` variable:

```
-(BOOL)validateEmail {

    if (self.ownUser.emailUser != self.emailField) {
        __block BOOL returnValue;

        [User validateEmail:self.emailField sucess:^(BOOL sucess, NSError *error) {
            if (sucess) {
                returnValue = YES;
            }else{
                NSLog(@"Can´t change e mail, already one is created in the database");
                returnValue = NO;
            }
        }];

        return returnValue;

    } else {
         return YES;
    }
}
```

The block itself (as I guess from the prototype) does not return a value.

Note that this will work only if `[User validateEmail:sucess:]` works *synchronously*, so that `returnValue` is defined when the function call returns.

Comment: Or better still have `[User validateEmail:sucess:]` return whatever was returned from the block...

Comment: @trojanfoe: It seemed to me that the block is more like a completion block for the validation, and does not return anything. But that is pure guessing and I might be wrong.

Comment: I agree; however if it returned a `BOOL` then `[User validateEmail:sucess:]` could simply pass that back, making it easier to use (it's easy to forget about the `__block` specifier).

Comment: @trojanfoe: Yes. - In fact you don't need a block at all if the validation works synchronously.

Comment: Yeah I think the OP is getting in a muddle.

Comment: I completely missed the correct solution, just changed my block to return an BOOL, and solve my problem.... Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You don't show the declaration of the method `[User validateEmail:sucess:]` (sic), but it looks like the block is declared as returning something other than `BOOL`.